# Umbraco Multiple File Upload upload button doesn't show inside Upload tab

Tags: asp.net, umbraco

I've scowered the Umbraco forum and no luck. My upload tab is showing, but the button isn't showing, I've had this bug before and have no luck getting it working.

The package says it's successfully installed, but the upload button doesn't show inside the upload tab, I've checked firebug and there are no errors present.

Has anyone else had this bug? Or know a way to fix it? Thanks

Comment: Make sure the Multiple File Upload datatype were created  in the developer section

Comment: Yip the datatype is there, and the usercontrol ascx file it links to, is there too.